Wallpaper files in Google Drive backup
I have a new Samsung tablet using Android 14. I have a Google Drive backup of the settings from my old Lenovo tablet using Android 13. I can't figure out how to get the wallpaper file to transfer from the backup to the new device.
Any easy solution that a non-techie could manage?
